# Prove that $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_4 \not\cong \Bbb{Z}_8$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to prove that the groups $\Bbb{Z}_2\ \otimes\ \Bbb{Z}_4 $ and $\Bbb Z_8$ are not isomorphic to each other.

I have figured out that the former has $2$ generators, while the latter has just $1$. Thus I should try to prove by contradiction that if a mapping exists between the generators of the former group and some group elements of the latter, there should be something wrong in it, like:
$$f(g_1)f(g_2) \neq f(g_1g_2)$$ a property which is highly important since it helps us to preserve the structure when we move to the *new* group.

But I am not being able to move beyond this. I am new to group theory so excuse me if this is trivial. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the tensor product rather than the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$? If you meant the direct product, then please replace $\otimes$ with $\times$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang This is the second time someone has said this to me about this notation. I guess the book I am following has it unconventional. I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isomorphisms preserve orders of elements.${}^\dagger$ Note that $\Bbb Z_8$ has an element of order $8$, whereas $\Bbb Z_2\otimes \Bbb Z_4$ does not.

---

$\dagger$ This means that for any group isomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ and any $g\in G$, we have $|g|=|\varphi (g)|$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? What does _preserving_ mean here. Someone else also told me this solution but I wasn't satisfied

Comment: Does that mean that we can only take an isomorphic mapping between elements of the same order?

Comment: I have edited my answer, @Sarthak. Yes, isomorphisms must map elements of a given order to elements of the same order.

Comment: @Sarthak Keep in mind that an isomorphism preserves products and is _invertible_. So if element $g$ has order $n$ in $G$, then $g^n=e$, so $\phi(g)^n=e$ and thus the order of $\phi(g)$ is at most $n$. What's more, if we had $\phi(g)^m=e$ for any $m\lt n$, then we could apply the inverse isomorphism to find that $\phi^{-1}\left(\phi(g)\right)^m=e$ and therefor $g^m=e$, contradicting our statement about the order of $g$.